# Xcode - push data into the firebase storage

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I  thought to design the program like this.

1. The user type the data in each text fields; Name, Passwords and Comments.
2. By press the button, store the input data into the Firebase storage.
3. However, the error occurred.

I wonder which parts need to fix or add.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INCUP.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VVla.jpg)

```
private let database = Database.database().reference()

@IBOutlet weak var NameInput: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Passwords: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Rate: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var Comment: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var UploadButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

@IBAction func UbuttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
   
    let review_data: [String: Any?] = [
        "Name": NameInput.text,
        "Passwords": Passwords.text,
        // "Rate": Rate.text,
        "Comment": Comment.text
    ]

    database.child("Review_\(Int.random(in: 0..<1000))").setValue(review_data)
}
```

Comment: `However, the error occurred.` So what error occurred? Please add a [mre] so we can see what you have tried so far. And reading [ask] could improve your question.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I uploaded the pictures, but it doesn't. Now I'm editing the post.

Comment: Don´t add code as images. Add it as code formatted text. So I can copy this in to XCode and see what has to be done.

Comment: Please don't use links - they break and if that happens, future readers will not know what the error was. Something to note is the error mentions `Rates` and there is no property `Rates` in the code, only `Rate`. So the code being shown is likely not the error. Search your project for `Rates` to see where it's used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a storyboard reference to one of the `@IBOutlets` which you renamed/deleted in your source code, but haven't removed/changed it in the storyboard. See [this article](https://becodable.com/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key/) for more info.